# GSM SIM-300 read msg problem

Tags: arduino, serial, gsm, at-commands

I'm unable to get a proper response from my GSM modem300, sometimes it responds with nothing, sometimes it replies half of line of ONE message from full inbox, sometimes it just sends the command (AT+CMGR=1) I just sent, back many times.

**Print screens:**

- sends my command back: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onkx6.jpg
- responds with nothing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU3A7.jpg
- responds with half line of one message from FULL inbox!: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTbl6.jpg
- responds with garbage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJkd8.jpg

I'm using Arduino, directly connecting the Tx and Rx of board to Rx and Tx of arduino, and GND to Arduino GND.

**CODE:**

```
char incomingByte=0; 
void setup() 
 {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGR=1");
  delay(2000); 
 }

 void loop()
 {   
    while (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {      
       incomingByte = Serial.read();              
       if(incomingByte!='\n'){ Serial.print(incomingByte); }
       if(incomingByte=='\n'){ Serial.print(incomingByte); }              
    }
 }
```

It might be worth mentioning that, I can send messages properly, and make and receive calls with no problem.

Comment: responds with half line of one message from FULL inbox!:
http://imgur.com/zsmDcIc

Comment: responds with garbage: http://imgur.com/vTVSwyf

Comment: sorry to do this, -_-' site won't let me post more than 2 links.

Comment: Instead of posting links of images of GUI windows of text, could you cut & paste the text? Use small representative samples (not pagefulls)

Comment: You are reading from serial in `incomingByte` and sending same byte on same serial! I am bit suspicious about this! And Not about problem, But You are doing same thing in `if(incomingByte != '\n') ` and `if(incomingByte == '\n') `... Why to write two conditions!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, as you can see the length is too long to post as text, screen-shot was my best bet.

Comment: @Swanand, I am still able to get a response though, but I'm just using the same serial to receive from one end and display from the other. Why does that line bother you? I may want to do something when the line reaches the end and something when it's in mid reply, how is that the same condition? example i may want to number the lines.

Comment: @user280353 What RedGrittyBrick said was my point!! You are Echoing your commands.. You are telling same thing to GSM modem what that modem told you!

Answer (score 1):

See http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

By using the same serial port to communicate with a modem and to communicate with your PC, you  are causing confusion.

- You are echoing the modem's reply back to the modem.
- Modems usually echo commands back to you.

I'd use separate channels as shown in the Arduino serial tutorial.

Last time I did something like this (with an Arduino communicating with a MIDI serial device) I used a 16x2 LCD to display what was being received. But you could use software serial if you prefer (or don't have a character LCD)

Comment: Thanks GrittyBrick, I've tried software serial in a different way, now I'll try it again with the same code design and see what happens. If it works I'll let you know.

Comment: Still no luck, this is the reply:  f~`8AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","52266001",,"08/08/19,12:09:0

Comment: no message body, not even other message headers

Comment: What happens if you replace the GSM modem with a wire link? Back in the day, we used to use a *Peripheral And Processor Electronic Reactive Communications Link Interface Probe* (P.A.P.E.R.C.L.I.P.)

Comment: Getting the command replied back to me on hardware Serial, but on Software Serial I'm getting gibberish; diff baud rates too.

Comment: Can't figure out what the damn problem is, I can properly read RFID tag numbers but this GSM modem is a curse. At first I thought it's faulty but the fact that it can call and send SMS is a reason to ponder.